# C# Using Reflection to subscribe to Events

Tags: c#, events, reflection, event-handling

I have a program where i am using Reflection to load classes dynamically based on a text file.

When i run my code i can get all the classes, methods and Events printing to screen and can even Invoke the methods.

I added all events to a Dictionary and i want to enumerate through them and then create a Event Handler to get the data sent by the event.

here is my method for getting the events to a dictionary:

```
 private Dictionary<string, EventInfo> RetrieveEvents(string label, string type)
    {
        try
        {
            this.displaysAssembly = Assembly.LoadFrom(Path.Combine(Directory.GetApplicationDirectory(), "Framework.DisplayDrivers.dll"));

            string assembly = string.Format("Framework.DisplayDrivers.{0}", type);
            Type cswitcher = displaysAssembly.GetType(assembly);

            fullClass = cswitcher;
            Dictionary<string, EventInfo> ekvp = new Dictionary<string, EventInfo>();
            List<EventInfo> eventInfos = cswitcher.GetEvents().Where(e => HasInformationAttribute(e)).ToList();

            foreach (var e in eventInfos)
            {                   
                if (!ekvp.ContainsKey(label))
                {
                    ekvp.Add(e.Name, e);
                }

            }

            return (ekvp);
        }
        catch (MissingMethodException e)
        {
            ErrorLog.Error(LogHeader + "Unable to create Display. No constructor: {0}", e.Message);
        }
        catch (ArgumentException e)
        {
            ErrorLog.Error(LogHeader + "Unable to create Display. No type: {0}", e.Message);
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException e)
        {
            ErrorLog.Error(LogHeader + "Unable to create Display. No match: {0}", e.Message);
        }


        return null;
    }
```

if I print out the Dictionary i can see the events by Key and Value.

but i cannot seem to create an Event handler. I have tried many options including:

```
foreach(var evnt in d._projectors._events)
                 {
                     EventInfo ev = evnt.Value;


                     try
                     {

                         // this id not work
                         object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(d._projectors.fullClass);
                         ev.AddEventHandler(classInstance, new EventHandler(DisplayChangeEvents.DisplayMuteChangedEvent));

                         // this did not work either

                         if (d._projectors._events.TryGetValue("OnPowerStateRecieved", out ev))
                         {
                             ev.AddEventHandler(ev.Name, new EventHandler(DisplayChangeEvents.DisplayPowerChangedEvent));                               
                         }

                     }
                     catch (Exception ex)
                     {

                         ErrorLog.Error("Error creating event handers :  " +  ex.Message + "\r");
                     }                      



                 }
```

i am trying to subscibe to the event and handle the data in another class named "DisplayChangeEvents".

i have been trying for 2 days to get this and its the last piece i need to get the program working as expected.

Thanks in advance

based on a suggestion i updated the code in the foreach loop to :

```
 foreach(var evnt in d._projectors._events)
                {
                    EventInfo ev = evnt.Value;


                    try
                    {

                        if (evnt.Key == "OnPowerStateRecieved")
                        {
                            ev.AddEventHandler(d._projectors.fullClass, new EventHandler(DisplayChangeEvents.DisplayPowerChangedEvent));
                        }
                        else if (evnt.Key == "OnMuteStateRecieved")
                        {
                            ev.AddEventHandler(d._projectors.fullClass, new EventHandler(DisplayChangeEvents.DisplayMuteChangedEvent));
                        }
                        // this id not work
                        // object classInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(d._projectors.fullClass);
                        //  ev.AddEventHandler(classInstance, new EventHandler(DisplayChangeEvents.DisplayMuteChangedEvent));

                        //ev.AddEventHandler(d._projectors.fullClass, new EventHandler(DisplayChangeEvents.DisplayMuteChangedEvent));

                        //// this did not work either

                        //if (d._projectors._events.TryGetValue("OnPowerStateRecieved", out ev))
                        //{
                        //    ev.AddEventHandler(ev.Name, new EventHandler(DisplayChangeEvents.DisplayPowerChangedEvent));                               
                        //}

                    }
```

get the following exception:

Specified cast is not valid.

the class that is creating the events looks like this:

```
 private static event EventHandler<PowerStateEventsArgs> _onPowerStateRecieved = delegate { };
    [Information(Description = "Power Event")]

    public static event EventHandler<PowerStateEventsArgs> OnPowerStateRecieved
    {
        add
        {
            if (!_onPowerStateRecieved.GetInvocationList().Contains(value))
            {
                 _onPowerStateRecieved += value;
            }
        }
        remove
        {
            _onPowerStateRecieved -= value;
        }
    }
```

the event that fires the event looks like this:

```
 if (i == 1)
                {
                    _onPowerStateRecieved(null, new PowerStateEventsArgs(true));
                }
```

this logic works in all other programs except when i am trying to reflection to create the classes dynamically.

Comment: Are you instantiating the `DisplayChangeEvents` class yourself or is your code running inside of another application and you are hooking into an existing instance?

Comment: the event is coming from a different namespace in a dll that contains multiple classes. When i invoke members of those classes that seems to work..  The DisplayChangeEvent in a class that resides in the current program. i am just passing the data there for easier parsing    The DisplayChangeEvents class is a static class

Comment: While you can create the class yourself and hook into the event handlers, who is going to invoke the event? Unless the class runs by itself upon construction, nothing is going to invoke the events you are hooking into. Is the library you using public? I can help you out more if I knew more details.

Comment: *"did not work"* is not helpful. Are you getting a compiler error, a runtime error, or some unexpected behavior when it finally runs? Things like how long you've spent on it and how many things you've tried are noise and can be removed; they don't matter. What matters is *what* you've tried and what the result was.

Comment: the other class is communicating with a device. When it gets the reply it fires the event.

Comment: Events are strongly typed, so you need to give us more information, such as the type of the event. `new EventHandler` is only going to work if the event is declared as `EventHandler`. If it's declared as any other type, you're going to have to instantiate *that* type instead.

Comment: Given that information, you need `new EventHandler<PowerStateEventsArgs>(...)`. If the type argument can differ, you're going to need to look into `MakeGenericMethod`.

Comment: And since it looks like you have the source code for the event, I should point out that "received" is spelled wrong.

Comment: can you show me an example of what you mean.  the lass that is firing the event has the event handler<PowerStateEventsArgs>.     I cannot add that to the main program because it does not know what it is.    I have used this same logic in other classes that I am not using reflection for and it always works.  Most other classes in the program work perfect with the logic.   It seems to be only with Reflection and subscribing to the event

Comment: since I use this in other classes I am 90% sure its not the event.    My error is consistently :Specified cast is not valid.  this is the part that does not seem to work. I cannot create a event handler that will listen to the events via reflection.

Comment: It's difficult to provide an answer that will be helpful given what you've provided. There are still unknowns, such as how much flexibility you need for different delegate types. Please build a [mre], and edit your post to contain that instead of what you have now. I don't think you've really thought it through enough, and building a minimal reproducible example will help with that tremendously.

Comment: Be very careful about asserting what you think it is or isn't, especially considering that you came here for help. If you don't understand the nuances of something and just dismiss it out of hand, that will block you every time.

Comment: I will try to create a minimal example.  Not sure yet how I will take apart what I have. Something’s I know that work I can omit.  Like I said the problem is creating the handler for the event.  The event will always just send a true or false in this particular case.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Thank you all for the advice.  I will strip this down to a minimal code base and try to replicate the issue I am having.  Will edit post with new code and any errors I get.

Answer (score 0):

I took the advice of the folks here and cut back my code and went back to basics with event handlers. I was able to load the drivers in my code via reflection and invoke the members, However I was unable to get the events working the way that I thought they would. I was able to just add in a switch-case and see which drivers were loaded and subscribed to the events manually.  Not ideal but if this group had not told me to cut back and go back to basics I would never have gotten as far as I did.    Thank you all